# HTML layout in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am new to [HTMLayout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTMLayout) and just know about the nabu library, and dont know how to create html based forms using nabu library, could anyone provide an example or opensource application that uses HTMLayout in a .Net setup?

Comment: Not sure why the 2 close votes; seems a reasonable question to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://dev.triflesoft.org/trac/nabu/browser/Sources/Examples) is the only example I could find in a bit of googling, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who are looking for Pure C# Html Layout Engine.

I want to introduce another Html Layout Engine , here **the HtmlRenderer**.

I forked https://github.com/LayoutFarm/HtmlRenderer from the original
Html-Renderer project, and added more HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript. It is under development, and has bugs; test it out, and feel free to comment, fork, discuss.

snapshot:  nearly pass ACID1 
[image]

---

compare with ACID1 reference on wikipedia
[image: acid1_reference]

(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid1)